# jQueryMobile Does not load with Phonegap on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Regular javascript works, however when I try to use jQuery or jQueryMobile, it does not load.
I have downloaded the compressed jQueryMobile file, and placed it in my project.

These are my script declarations in my HTML file

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquerymobile.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/myscript.js"></script>
```

This is the function in myscript.js that is not firing:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert('at least this works');
    });
```

I can see in logcat this error message:

```
06-06 14:57:19.555: D/CordovaLog(249): file:///android_asset/www/js/myscript.js: Line 15 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

Which prompts me to believe that jQueryMobile isn't loading at all. The other solutions that I found regarding this error message did not work for me. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I added jQuery and swapped out deviceready for pageinit. I am still getting errors.

My new script declarations are:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquerymobile.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/myscript.js"></script>
```

My new function that is not being called is:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () 
    { 
        alert('at least this works');
    });
```

And Here are some interesting error messages from logcat:

```
06-06 15:16:39.777: D/CordovaLog(219): file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.js: Line 3345 : TypeError: Result of expression 'Object.defineProperty' [undefined] is not a function.

06-06 15:16:40.747: D/CordovaLog(219): file:///android_asset/www/js/jquerymobile.js: Line 26 : TypeError: Result of expression '$' [undefined] is not an object.

06-06 15:16:40.757: D/CordovaLog(219): file:///android_asset/www/js/myscript.js: Line 15 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

Comment: where are you loading jquery itself?

Comment: Because `.ready` doesn't work with jQueryMobile. use `pageinit` instead. `$(document).on('pageinit', function () { alert(); });` Also you have to include jQuery with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @Omar Edited my question to reflect new issues.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @Gajotres It is Jquery 2.0.2, and JqueryMobile 1.3.1

Comment: Please downgrade your jQuery to version 1.9.1 or 1.8.3

Comment: @Gajotres Success! If you want to post your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade your jQuery version from **`2.0.2`** to **`1.9.1`** or **`1.8.3`**

jQuery Mobile is locked to certain jQuery versions and current jQuery Mobile **`1.3.1`** will work with jQuery **`1.7`** up to **`1.9.3.`**